# How to detect indexPath.row in CustomCell button Click?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell. like this

[image: Cell]

There are buttons, like LIKE, COMMENT, SHARE.

I want indexPath.row in method when click these buttons.

I made protocol like this

```
@protocol Cell_StreamCellDelegate
@required

-(void)like;
-(void)comment;
-(void)share;


@end
```

I called them when methods in CELL.m like as below

```
-(IBAction)likePressed:(id)sender{
    [delegate like];
}
-(IBAction)commentPressed:(id)sender{
    [delegate comment];
}
-(IBAction)sharePressed:(id)sender{
    [delegate share];
}
```

But I am unable to fetch the indexPath.row. I want get an object which is on particular index.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new integer property as row in custom cell subclass then assign its value as indexpath.row in cellForRowAtIndex method.

```
customcell.row = indexpath.row.
```

Use this row in protocol

```
 [delegate like:row]
```

Comment: I did it now, before your post, let me test it, I will appreciate if it works

Answer (score 0):

In your delegate methods you could send the cell that called the methods (i. e. `self`)

Something like:

```
- (void)commentForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
```

When you call the delegate method do it like

```
[delegate commentForCell:self];
```

Then when you implement the delegate method

```
- (void)commentForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    ...
}
```

It is very common to use the caller as a param in a delegate method, as you can see in any standard SDK protocol (collection view, table view, alert view...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one , Just converting the `touched points into the cell Index`:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; 
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
```